# Not getting data from Index() laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to fetch all data from table and send to view file through controller. Unfortunately it is not happening. I know it is a simple mistake. But couldn't sort it out yet. My stuffs are given below :

Controller:

```
public function index()
{

  $categories = Category::all();

  return View::make('manage-category')
   ->with('categories', $categories);
}
```

model:

```
class Category extends \Eloquent {
  protected $table = 'categories';
}
```

view:

```
var_dump($categories);
die();
```

routes:

```
Route::get('/manage-category', function()
{
    return View::make('manage-category');
});
```

it shows : Undefined variable "categories" in view file.

EXPERTs help me out ..

Comment: Are you sure the controller action even runs? Place a `die()` in your index method and see what happens...

Comment: no nothing is happening .. page loads ..

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the routes please?

Comment: ok i am updating .. i put this stuff : $categories = Category::all();
        var_dump($categories);
        die();

Comment: Your router just returns View instead of calling your Controller
So, you simply need to replace your routes with this
`Route::get('/manage-category','YourControllerName@index')`

Comment: thanks comodo I figured it out .. yes I did the stuff u suggested although before ur suggestion. Anyway thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Finally I figured it out. I had to write my Routes like this way :

```
Route::get('/manage-category','CategoryController@index');
```